# kdevelop #include

Tags: c++, eigen, kdevelop

The Kdevelop wiki [says (bottom of the page)](http://userbase.kde.org/KDevelop4/FAQ)

*For cases where KDevelop is still not figuring out the include path properly after you have configured your build toolchain, you can manually add include paths on a per-directory basis into a .kdev_include_paths file. This can be done from inside KDevelop by running the "solve problem" wizard associated with a "could not find include file" problem, e.g. by hovering the problematic #include line.*

Now, i have done this (and there are no longer any problematic, underlined, #include line). But when i try to build, i get:

```
~/projects/mqncpptest/build> make
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/mqncpptest.dir/main.cpp.o
~/projects/mqncpptest/main.cpp:15:23: fatal error: Eigen/Dense: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

user BЈовић asks for more information:

I followed the KDEvelop instruction for a minimal compile. Project->new from template -> standard (simple C make based c++ application). Version control system is "none" and cmake directory is: /usr/bin/cmake. Then KDEvelop underlined `#include <Eigen/Dense>`, i clicked on "add custom include path" pop up on the lower end of the screen, entered the path the eigen, which removed the underlining of `#include <Eigen/Dense>` and then Build and then i get `/home/kaveh/projects/mqn_get/main.cpp:15:23: fatal error: Eigen/Dense: No such file or directory`. I should add that this code builds without a problem in eclipse and from the shell.

Motivation: I'm trying to build it under kdevelop because i need to use a debugger (the code doesn't give the intended results) and eclipse is just *too* heavy IMO.

Comment: Can you add details to your question? How you created project? Can you post cmake file (if your project uses cmake?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did is that you included a directory for the parser, but not for the build. In order to do that, you need to modify your make file.

For g++, you need to use [-I](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html) option.

Comment: Would you know where is the make file? --i've never used Cmake before (i'm usually compiling from the terminal)

Answer (score 2):

You should include

```
#include "Eigen/Dense"
```

rather than

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
```

The last one is for includes in system headers directories